# VS Code Debug Console how to access closure functions?

Tags: javascript, closures, vscode-debugger

I'm fiddling around with the VS Code Debug Console in order to better understand this tool.

I'll use this snippet as example:

```js
function printRandom() {
    console.log(Math.random());
}

function callPrintRandom() {
    printRandom();
}

function main() {
    debugger; // breakpoint
    callPrintRandom();
}

main();
```

If I check the debugger I can confirm both `printRandom` and `callPrintRandom` are in the `main` closure scope.

[image]

But when I try to call them directly in the debug console I can only call `callPrintRandom()`, even though `printRandom()` is in located in the `main` closure scope

[image: debug console]

Why can't I call `printRandom()` if vs code is stating that it is inside the main closure?

Is there any special word I should use when referencing closure objects?

I got to this question because I was trying to use the VS Code Debug Console as a REPL for my code, but I can't seem to access all the context I'm in when at a breakpoint.